# Call one CTE in another CTE

Tags: sql, t-sql

How could I call a CTE in another CTE ?

```
WITH cte1
AS (
    SELECT City.*
    FROM City
    WHERE (City.CityName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) LIKE 'são paulo'
)
, cte2
AS (
    SELECT Imovel.Imovel_Id 
    FROM Imovel
    WHERE Imovel.Number = 311
    AND Imovel.ZIPCode = '30280490'
    AND Imovel.Complement = ''
    AND Imovel.Street = 'Do furquim'
        -- the line below has an error in cte.City_Id
    AND Imovel.City_Id = cte1.City_Id 
)
```

Comment: You can't use a column from a table that's not in your `FROM` or `JOIN` clause...You need to `JOIN` that CTE to query it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to join both like with a normal table:

```
WITH cte1 
     AS (SELECT city.* 
         FROM   city 
         WHERE  ( city.cityname COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai ) LIKE 
                'são paulo'), 
     cte2 
     AS (SELECT imovel.imovel_id 
         FROM   imovel 
                INNER JOIN cte1 
                        ON imovel.city_id = cte1.city_id 
         WHERE  imovel.number = 311 
                AND imovel.zipcode = '30280490' 
                AND imovel.complement = '' 
                AND imovel.street = 'Do furquim') 
SELECT * FROM   cte2
```

Note that i have appended `SELECT * FROM   cte2` since CTE's cannot "stand" alone.

Comment: Is it possible to make one of those CTE's recursive - let's say, cte2 ? I know that your example is not meant to be recursive, but I need recursion on just one of my CTE's, which depends on another CTE's.

Comment: @FrenkyB: Yes, sure :)